# Backing up docker volumes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I've created a separate volume on an Ubuntu machine with the intention to store docker volumes and persist data. So far, I've created volumes on the host machine for two services (jira and postgres), which I intent to backup offsite. I am using `docker-compose` like so

postgres:

```
volumes:
   - /var/dkr/pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

And for jira:

```
volumes:
   - /var/dkr/jira:/var/atlassian/jira
```

My thinking is that I could just rsync the `/var/dkr` folder to a temporary location, `tar` it and send it to S3. Now that I've read a bit more on the process of hosted volumes I am worried that I might end up with messed up GIDs and UIDs for the services when I restore from a backup.

My questions are - has docker resolved this problem in the newer versions (I am using the latest). Is it safe to take this approach? What would be a better way to backup my persistent volumes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no magic solution to uid/gid mapping issues between containers and hosts. It would need to be implemented by the filesystem drivers in the Linux kernel, which is how NFS and some of the VM filesystem mappings work. For "bind" mounts, forcing a uid/gid is not an option from Linux, and Docker is just providing an easy to use interface on top of that.

With your backups, ensure that uid/gid is part of your backup (tar does this by default). Also ensure that the uid/gid being used in your container is defined in the image or specified to a static value in your `docker run` or compose file. As long as you don't depend on a host specific uid/gid, and restore preserving the uid/gid (default for tar as root), you won't have any trouble.

Worst case, you run something like `find /var/dkr -uid $old_uid -exec chown $new_uid {} \;` to change your UID's. The tar command also has options for change uid/gid on extract (see the man page for more details).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please elaborate a little bit around "... or specified to a static value in your docker run or compose file"? Particularly interested in the compose file bit. Thanks

Comment: @Ando With `docker run` there's a `-u` option to specify a uid/gid. And with a compose file, there's a `user` field [documented here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir). Those override the `USER` setting in your Dockerfile or upstream image.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will look into it.